# How to Detect "Your homepage displays" setting in wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I simply want to detect what user has selected from these settings. [image]

Because i need to display the homepage content according to this setting. For example, if user select "Your latest Posts" i want to display a list of posts.
If user select "A static page" i want to display the content of that page. I don't know if any wordpress built-in php function exist or not to detect these settings.

Comment: You shouldn't need to check the settings. You just need to use the right templates: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview

Comment: It should be simple, I have 2 solutions for it, are u familiar with Theme Development and templates? One is advanced and effectient, other is much simpler "Hack", so which one should I tell

Comment: Seems like i have to learn about templates. However, i would like to know that simpler solution